# SonarQube plugin criptic error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, sonarqube, bitbucket

Could you help me understand this error message from [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/)?

I'm working for a university project. The error is not present when I run it on my computer with my local sonar but for some reason when I load it on my bitbucket repository and the reviewer wants to test it, he can't compile!

I made sure the configuration is right, but still something is wrong.

```
[WARN] [10:33:51.621] SQL Error: 50200, SQLState: HYT00 
[ERROR]
[10:33:51.622] Timeout trying to lock table "DEPENDENCIES"; SQL
statement: insert into dependencies (id, from_resource_id, from_scope,
from_snapshot_id, parent_dependency_id, project_snapshot_id,
to_resource_id, to_scope, to_snapshot_id, dep_usage, dep_weight)
values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [50200-176] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] Total time: 22.008 s 
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-05-13T10:33:51+02:00 
[INFO] Final Memory: 33M/438M 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal
org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.5:sonar (default-cli) on
project cg_11: Unable to deserialize dependency information:
[{"k":"junit:junit","v":"4.12","s":"test","d":[{"k":"org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core","v":"1.3","s":"test","d":[]}]}]:
Unable to persist :
DependencyDto[id=<null>,fromSnapshotId=126848,fromResourceId=5080,fromScope=PRJ,toSnapshotId=4,toResourceId=4,toScope=PRJ,weight=1,usage=test,projectSnapshotId=126848,parentDependencyId=<null>]:
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert:
[org.sonar.api.design.DependencyDto]: Timeout trying to lock table
"DEPENDENCIES"; SQL statement: [ERROR] insert into dependencies (id,
from_resource_id, from_scope, from_snapshot_id, parent_dependency_id,
project_snapshot_id, to_resource_id, to_scope, to_snapshot_id,
dep_usage, dep_weight) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
[50200-176] [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.5:sonar
(default-cli) on project cg_11: Unable to deserialize dependency
information:
[{"k":"junit:junit","v":"4.12","s":"test","d":[{"k":"org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core","v":"1.3","s":"test","d":[]}]}]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to
deserialize dependency information:
[{"k":"junit:junit","v":"4.12","s":"test","d":[{"k":"org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core","v":"1.3","s":"test","d":[]}]}]
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:139)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to
deserialize dependency information:
[{"k":"junit:junit","v":"4.12","s":"test","d":[{"k":"org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core","v":"1.3","s":"test","d":[]}]}]
    at org.sonar.batch.design.MavenDependenciesSensor.analyse(MavenDependenciesSensor.java:182)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:59)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:51)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.execute(DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.java:120)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:264)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:235)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:230)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:220)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:57)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:45)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:158)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:135)
    ... 22 more Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable
to persist :
DependencyDto[id=<null>,fromSnapshotId=126848,fromResourceId=5080,fromScope=PRJ,toSnapshotId=4,toResourceId=4,toScope=PRJ,weight=1,usage=test,projectSnapshotId=126848,parentDependencyId=<null>]
    at org.sonar.jpa.session.JpaDatabaseSession.internalSave(JpaDatabaseSession.java:136)
    at org.sonar.jpa.session.JpaDatabaseSession.save(JpaDatabaseSession.java:103)
    at org.sonar.batch.index.DependencyPersister.saveInDB(DependencyPersister.java:82)
    at org.sonar.batch.index.DependencyPersister.saveDependency(DependencyPersister.java:57)
    at org.sonar.batch.index.DefaultIndex.addDependency(DefaultIndex.java:288)
    at org.sonar.batch.deprecated.DeprecatedSensorContext.saveDependency(DeprecatedSensorContext.java:219)
    at org.sonar.batch.design.MavenDependenciesSensor.saveDependencies(MavenDependenciesSensor.java:232)
    at org.sonar.batch.design.MavenDependenciesSensor.analyse(MavenDependenciesSensor.java:180)
    ... 54 more Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert:
[org.sonar.api.design.DependencyDto]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:614)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:226)
    at org.sonar.jpa.session.JpaDatabaseSession.internalSave(JpaDatabaseSession.java:130)
    ... 61 more Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException:
could not insert: [org.sonar.api.design.DependencyDto]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2176)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2656)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:646)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:620)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:624)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:220)
    ... 62 more Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Timeout trying
to lock table "DEPENDENCIES"; SQL statement: insert into dependencies
(id, from_resource_id, from_scope, from_snapshot_id,
parent_dependency_id, project_snapshot_id, to_resource_id, to_scope,
to_snapshot_id, dep_usage, dep_weight) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
?, ?, ?, ?) [50200-176]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:344)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:178)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:154)
    at org.h2.table.RegularTable.doLock(RegularTable.java:530)
    at org.h2.table.RegularTable.lock(RegularTable.java:464)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:155)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:115)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:79)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:254)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.process(TcpServerThread.java:346)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:160) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:606)
    at org.h2.command.CommandRemote.executeUpdate(CommandRemote.java:192)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:158)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:144)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:57)
    ... 77 more 
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1]
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
SonarQube analysis completed: FAILURE Build step 'SonarQube' changed
build result to FAILURE Build step 'SonarQube' marked build as failure
```

Comment: did you restart the build once again? Sometime the sonar database have some problems, after restart it runs good.

Comment: There might was another task working on the database, especially table `DEPENDENCIES`, which didn't finish within the timeout of the database. You might want to check that timeout and maybe increase it.